# Lebesgue density 1/2 (or bounded away from 0 and 1)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

From the work of Preiss, we know that in infinite-dimensional spaces, one has violations of the Lebesgue density theorem. In particular, he has constructed examples of probability spaces where a set of positive measure has Lebesgue density zero at all points. Question: is there an example of a set of positive measure whose Lebesgue density is bounded away from 0 and 1 everywhere?

Edit: to be more specific, I am looking for a metric probability space and a measurable set with positive measure such that its Lebesgue density is bounded away from 0 and 1 almost everywhere.